# Multi-table Query Join

Tags: php, mysql, join

Since I am new to PHP, i am finding this immensely complicated to solve.  I have this query that is showing results that a user is not supposed to do.

The problem is the sales agent is able to see complaints from users he is not authorized to see.  This pertains to the accounts table, which is for the customers.

```
$priv = "dire problem" , 
$naone = "not serious" , 
$priv2 = "mild prblem" 
are sorting conditions. 
$aid is the agent viewing this page.  

Complaints is for complaints by the customers. 
Accounts table holds all the customer information. 
Agents table is for all the sales/customer reps.
```

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT complaints.complaint_id, accounts.full_name,
agents.agent_name, complaints.person_id, complaints.why_complaint, 
complaints.just_date, complaints.type, complaints.date_time_added FROM 
complaints LEFT JOIN accounts ON complaints.person_id = accounts.person_id 
LEFT JOIN agents on complaints.agent_whois = agents.agent_id WHERE 
(complaint_type = '$priv' OR complaint_type = '$naone' OR complaint_type = '$priv2') and  
 (complaints.added_by <> '$aid')"; 
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

 $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

 if ($result == "")
 {
 echo "";
 }
 echo "";


 $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($rows == 0)
 {
 print("");

 }
 elseif($rows > 0)
 {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {

  $complaintid = $row['complaint_id'];
  $agentwho = $row['person_id'];
  $agentname = $row['agent_name'];
 $reason = $row['why_complaint'];
 $datetimeadded = $row['just_date'];
  $docname = $row['full_name'];
  $type = $row['type'];


   print("");
   }

    }
```

Comment: i was ediiting it with the question

Comment: Confused, are you trying to limit the view to show only those in which have been assigned to that agent, or are you trying to limit it to agents by permission level?

Comment: BTW: This code has SQL injection vulnerabilities which would make it easy to hack.

Comment: what are the vulnerabilities? As i mentioned I am new.

Comment: Considering we have no knowledge of your tables structure, you will have to shed more light on the issue. Should he see complaints added by himself? Should he see only complaints the he didn't add by himself? How do you determine which complaint should he see and which he shouldn't?

Comment: @johnfx by agent's permission level.

Comment: This article explains the vulnerability: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @DvirAzulay You are right it has to do with levels.  So $priv is for dire situtations so he gets to see it for customers under him that were added by not added by his customers but other agents who have mutual customers, $naone is for situations added by 3rd party and $priv2 is for situations added by his customers.

Comment: @johnfx i got the point but where in this script do you see vulneratbility.  ONly variables that are there are the ones used by agents and nobody else.  There is no user input that is being used.

Comment: I couldn't tell from your script where the inputs actually came from. Just beware of inserting any string into a SQL statement that a user can manipulate.

Comment: @johnfx so in any case its good to use Mysql_real_escape_string, correct?

Comment: Absolutely. Any time you are concatenating variables into SQL strings there is the potential for trouble. Better safe than sorry.BTW: If you add your table definition to your question we might have an easier time answering it.

Comment: ok i updated with the table definition.

Comment: By "table definition", we generally mean a list of the columns in each table, and a description of what kind of data each column contains.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not really an answer, but I'm posting it anyway since it's the best I can do.*

OK, first of all, your indentation is all over the place.  *Please*, for the sake of anyone who needs to read your code, use a consistent [indentation style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).  It doesn't really matter which style you use — just pick one and apply it consistently.  It makes you code much easier to read.

That said, let's take a look at your query.  Here it is in its original form, just reindented for better readability:

```
SELECT
  complaints.complaint_id,
  accounts.full_name,
  agents.agent_name,
  complaints.person_id,
  complaints.why_complaint, 
  complaints.just_date,
  complaints.type,
  complaints.date_time_added
FROM
  complaints
  LEFT JOIN accounts ON complaints.person_id = accounts.person_id 
  LEFT JOIN agents ON complaints.agent_whois = agents.agent_id
WHERE
  ( complaint_type = '$priv'
    OR complaint_type = '$naone'
    OR complaint_type = '$priv2' )
  AND (complaints.added_by <> '$aid')
```

In fact, we can rewrite the `WHERE` clause a bit more compactly like this:

```
WHERE
  complaint_type IN ('$priv', '$naone', '$priv2')
  AND complaints.added_by <> '$aid'
```

But all this says is that `complain_type` must be one of the three values, and that the complaint must not have been added by the agent `'$aid'`.  You say that

> "The problem is the sales agent is able to see complaints from users he is not authorized to see."

but there's absolutely nothing in the query about any kind of authorization at all!  Since I can't even guess from the query what kind of authorization data your tables might contain, or what you want to do with it, the only advice I can give you is to figure out some rules to tell the records that should be shown from those that shouldn't be and *add them to the query*.